# Unable to set image into ImageView from a ListView using SimpleAdapter, ViewBinder and Asynctask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-viewbinder

I have a problem. I'm trying to retrieve an image from a online source and the set the image into the `ListView`'s `ImageView`. However, I can't do that because I can't link my `ImageView` within the `ListView` as it returns a `NullPointerException`. I realise that I have to use `VieWBinder` to set the image into the `ImageView` within the `ListView`.
Currently, I'm using the `ImageLoader` class from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java?r=4) as well as the `ViewBinder` class from [here](http://www.anddev.org/post98388.html#p98388).
This is my ViewBinder Class:

```
SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();
ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
    if (view instanceof ImageView && data instanceof Bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < sr.listData.size(); i++) {
            String imageISBN = sr.listData.get(i).get("coverImage");
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
            imageDownloader.download(imageISBN,iv);
            //iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`SearchResults` is a class where I got the listData from which contains data like the url to the images. How can I do use the `ImageLoader` class to insert the downloaded image into the `ImageView` within the `ListView` using `ViewBinder`?

*Side Note: It would give me an error "05-12 13:16:37.195: INFO/System.out(736): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://lib.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn=9780137081851/SC.GIF&client=tpoly&type=xw12
 " as well ***

Answer (score 0):

Set tag for the image view say for instance the URL of the image. And in your onPostExecute fetch the image view by list view.findViewByTag. I don't agree using asynctask for fetching images as there would be many asynctask if your list view is having lot of list items.